# c# smalldate pass to sql server proc

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass date to a sql procedure,  the time is being passed, and causing the proc to fail, because the times do not match,  c# is passing date 12:00:00 database shows date 00:00:00

so here is my code

```
public class
datetime dt_value;
```

get the date from the javascript calendar

```
DT_Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["TextBox_Tracking_ImportDate"]);
```

try to convert to mm/dd/yyyy

```
string DT_Value2 = DT_Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

pass date to sql

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@import_date", DT_Value2));


ERROR: Error converting data type nvarchar to smalldatetime.
```

Comment: In what way does calling `ToString("ddMMyyyy")` "try to convert to mm/dd/yyyy" out of interest?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the `DateTime` directly..

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@import_date", DT_Value);
```

See [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is the first problem:

```
string DT_Value2 = DT_Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@import_date", DT_Value2));
```

You're performing a pointless string conversion, and as a result you're corrupting the data. Just don't do it. *Always* avoid string conversions as far as you possibly can.

Pass the `DateTime` directly:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@import_date", DT_Value));
```

Or better, specify the type explicitly:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@import_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DT_Value;
```

Or to just take the date part explicitly from the `DateTime`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@import_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DT_Value.Date;
```

To be honest though, if your SQL code actually knows that the parameter is a `Date` rather than a `DateTime`, there shouldn't even be the *concept* of a time part. If you could post your SQL, that would help us diagnose that aspect. It's really important to work out the right types to use - it makes life so much simpler.

Comment: thanks John here is the sql procALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dddddd_id_MERGE]

(
 claim_id nvarchar(15)
 ,import_date smalldatetime
)

AS
BEGIN

 SELECT TrackingStatus,  PRF1, PRF2, PRF3, Comments, Spare, SpareFinished, MEMBER_ID
 FROM dbo.ClosedClaims_MERGE (NOLOCK)
 WHERE claim_id = claim_id
    and date_imported = import_date

END